# how to get just 1 object of json in java using twitter4j?

Tags: java, json, api, twitter, twitter4j

i want to ask. how can i get just the username of this json in java? i am using twitter4j to fetch twitter data. Sorry i am new to java. This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(accessTokenStr,
                accessTokenSecretStr);

        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                    User user = twitter.showUser(345569492);
                    System.out.println(user);

                } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
                    te.getErrorMessage();
                }

}
```

and this is the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMycJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `user.getName()` which will return the full name of an user. Or you can call `user.getScreenName()` which will return the twitter handle.